# Extra space beneath unordered list using string resource in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Okay so I am making a simple, single activity app in android studio. It has an <ImageView> and a <TextView> inside a <RelativeLayout> in such a manner that the text is on the right of the image.
The <TextView> shows an unordered list and I have made this unordered list using the "ul" and "li" tags in the string.xml resource.

`<string name="answer1">Contact us on<ul><li>Whatsapp</li><li>Mail</li></ul></string>`

The problem I have is that there is some extra space beneath the list as if there is another invisible list item, and I have no clue why. This makes it a little off when using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` [Screenshot of the layout validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZJSB.png)

I know that there must be better ways to make an unordered list with bullet points but my objective is to only use the string resource.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hi_logo"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hi_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hi_logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is just basic HTML formatting. If you were to view the code as a web page you would see the same behavior.
One option is to use the "\n" new line character and the bullet unicode (•)to make your own list.
Contact us on\n•Whatsapp\n•Mail
The \n causes the line break and the unicode code adds a bullet.